# Proof of transfer function factorization $\frac{b_0}{a_0} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^M (1-c_kz^{-1})}{\prod_{k=1}^N(1-d_kz^{-1})}$

Tags: transfer-function

This is from Oppenheim's Discrete-Time Signal Processing, but the book doesn't seem to describe how the factorization is done.

---

The transfer function:

$$H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^M b_kz^{-k}}{\sum_{k=0}^Na_kz^{-k}}$$

can be factored to the form:

$$\frac{b_0}{a_0} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^M (1-c_kz^{-1})}{\prod_{k=1}^N(1-d_kz^{-1})}$$

where each of the factors $(1-c_kz^{-1})$ contribute a zero at $z=c_k$ and pole at $z=0$. Similarly $(1-d_kz^{-1})$ contributes a zero at $z=0$ and a pole at $z=d_k$.

How is the above factorization done?
Is this the only representation?

Comment: These two forms simply follow from the fact that you can represent a [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) either by its polynomial coefficients or by its zeros.

Comment: As for how it's done, you need a polynomial root finder such as matlab's `roots` function.

Comment: Keep in mind that the numerator and denominator are factored individually. And yes - this is the only representation.

Comment: @chris_m I believe here is given a slightly different form: http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2ZPK.html

Comment: @mavavilj Thank's for your link. Do you mean with slightly different form, that in the link they allow for complex $c_k$ and $d_k$ ?

Comment: @chris_m No I mean that there's no term 1 in $(1-c_kz^{-1})$ (although in the link the transfer function isn't even in z-transformed form), but rather some variable $s$.

Comment: @mavavilj Thank you! Now I understand what you mean. I should have thought twice before writing there was no other representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mere application of the fundamental theorem of algebra of polynomials in 1D, which states that **any** polynomial $p(x)$ of $x$ of degree $n$, can be written (expressed) in either increasing (or decreasing) powers of $x$ as in $$p(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}x+a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_kx^{n-k}}$$  or as a product of its $n$ roots in the factors of $(x-r_k)$ as in $$p(x) = K(x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_n)=K\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x-r_n)$$ where each such factor represents a root of the polynomial $p(x)$.

The $n^{th}$ degree poynomial is assumed to have $n$ roots, either distinct or repeating or in complex and/or complex conjugate forms, depending on the coefficients $a_k$.

Applying this to the $Z$-Transform of the form discussed:
$$X(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{M}{a_nz^{-n}}=a_0+a_1z^{-1}+...+a_Mz^{-M}$$ this can be seen either as a polynomial in the variable $z^{-1}$, or after factoring out $a_0z^{-M}$ ($a_0$ being nonzero) it will be a polynomials in $z$ as given $$X(z)=a_0z^{-M}\left(z^{M}+\frac{a_1}{a_0}z^{M-1}+...+\frac{a_M}{a_0}\right)$$ And the paranthesis can be written in product form as: 
$$X(z)= a_0z^{-M}\prod_{k=1}^{M}{(z-r_k)}$$
You can distribute the factor $z^{-M}$ into each product form as in: $$z^{-1}(z-p_m) = (1-p_mz^{-1}) $$ which yields the final required form as: 
$$X(z) = a_0 \prod_{k=1}^{M}(1 - r_k z^{-1})$$ where each $r_k$ is a root.

When $X(z)$ is expressed as a rational traform as in $$X(z)= \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{M}{b_kz^{-k}}}{\sum_{k=0}^{N}{a_kz^{-k}}} $$ apply this factorization to both of numerator and denominator to get the final form:$$X(z)= \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{M}{b_kz^{-k}}}{\sum_{k=0}^{N}{a_kz^{-k}}}=\frac{b_0}{a_0} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{M}{(1-c_kz^{-1})}}{\prod_{k=1}^{N}{(1-d_kz^{-1})}}$$

Comment: Can you explain the bit of factoring $z^{-M}$ "into" each product form better?

Comment: take for example M=3 then: $z^{-3} = z^{-1}z^{-1}z^{-1}$ And there are also M=3 product factors such as $z^{-3}(z-r_1)(z-r_2)(z-r_3)$, and by distributing each factor $z^{-1}$ into a product you will get: $z^{-1}(z-r_1) \times z^{-1}(z-r_2) \times z^{-1}(z-r_3) = (1-r_1z^{-1}) \times (1-r_2z^{-1}) \times (1-r_3z^{-1})$ So now $z^{-3}$ is distributed into the products.